# Delete and completely remove the commit from git history

Tags: git, github, push, git-commit, post-commit

I have a commits in my git history

```
1.commit 4930da17d8dd23d650ed38435d8b421816a0c451
  Date:   Sat Dec 5 14:34:18 2015 +0530

2.commit e1ebbbb599ee20ebec3ca92c26266d9fd16e7ccc
  Date:   Sat Dec 5 13:22:20 2015 +0530

3.commit 1c4a11a80eb054d24dafec2efed0b0282188e687
  Date:   Sat Dec 5 12:11:50 2015 +0530

4.commit b4ab3c164a3a8d93e0a71a94b5c561cb5e20ebf6
  Date:   Sat Dec 5 12:09:56 2015 +0530

5.commit 167b1d10258381f09663ce61fa88ce3bbcd404c4
  Date:   Sat Dec 5 12:09:21 2015 +0530

6.commit c61bcadac673e1c83f4c14b66d56e23b12fa3198
  Date:   Sat Dec 5 12:07:58 2015 +0530
```

In that 3rd and 4th commit contains a wrong code, but unknowingly I committed and pushed.

```
3.commit 1c4a11a80eb054d24dafec2efed0b0282188e687
  Date:   Sat Dec 5 12:11:50 2015 +0530

4.commit b4ab3c164a3a8d93e0a71a94b5c561cb5e20ebf6
  Date:   Sat Dec 5 12:09:56 2015 +0530
```

But 5th and 6th commits contains a correct code. I need this commit to work.

```
5.commit 167b1d10258381f09663ce61fa88ce3bbcd404c4
  Date:   Sat Dec 5 12:09:21 2015 +0530

6.commit c61bcadac673e1c83f4c14b66d56e23b12fa3198
  Date:   Sat Dec 5 12:07:58 2015 +0530
```

Now I want to Delete and Remove completely whatever I changed in 3rd and 4th commit.

I want delete 3rd and 4th commit from the git history. But not 5th and 6th.

So that my branch will be safe.

Comment: if you fixed it, you wouldnt have to delete those commits

Comment: that is completely different. I am sure. I want to delete . I dont want those two commits. Because of that I am not able to move further.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `interactive rebase` in order to go back in your commit history and do things differently. For using interactive rebase, just:

```
git rebase -i <commit_id>
```

`<commit_id>` is the parent of the last commit you want to edit. After executing this command, just put `d` or `drop` in front of commits you're gonna delete or even delete the line corresponding to that commit.

Running this command gives you a list of commits in your text editor that looks something like this:

```
pick f7f3f6d changed my name a bit
pick 310154e updated README formatting and added blame
pick a5f4a0d added cat-file

# Rebase 710f0f8..a5f4a0d onto 710f0f8
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

The interactive rebase gives you a script that it’s going to run. It will start at the commit you specify on the command line and replay the changes introduced in each of these commits from top to bottom. It lists the oldest at the top, rather than the newest, because that’s the first one it will replay.

But since you've pushed the branch to your upstream repository, do communicate this history rewrite to your possible colleagues, as the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) says:

> Remember again that this is a rebasing command – every commit included
>   in the range will be rewritten, whether you change the
>   message or not. Don’t include any commit you’ve already pushed to a
>   central server – doing so will confuse other developers by providing
>   an alternate version of the same change.

Comment: imo, it's the best option. just run `git rebase -i HEAD~6` and replace `pick` with `d`, before commits you're going to delete. Then, save and close the editor.

Comment: Why use `drop`? `drop` isn't listed as a valid command in the help that `rebase -i` prints, but the help is explicit that deleting or commenting out a line removes it from history.

Comment: `drop` or `d` would work but you're right, deleting the line is more natural~

Answer (score 8):

You can interactively rewrite history with git rebase -i:

```
git rebase HEAD~6 -i
```

Will open your editor and allow you to either squash multiple commits into one, or completely remove them from history (by deleting the line for those commits in your editor.) The ~6 means rewrite the last 6 commits, the -i means do it interactively. In your case, you'll want to remove the lines that say "pick 1c4a11a" and "pick b4ab3c".

Note that the most recent commit in the editor that gets launched is the *last* line, not the first one, and since you're rewriting history and you've already pushed, you'll also have to "git push --force", not just "git push" in order to send your changes upstream.

Comment: The exact command I was looking for - still saving lives over 4 years later :)

Comment: Yes agreed! Be sure to use git push --force